# Display Numbers While/For Nested Loop

Tags: java, loops, numbers, nested

Java: How can I create a program to display the numbers 1 - 25 consecutively while creating a new line after every 5 numbers? How can I do this using a nested loop? I have been trying to wrap my head around the concept, but couldn't.

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: You don't need any nested loop to insert a new line for every five items...

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<5;i++){for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){Console.Write(i*5+j);}Console.WriteLine();}`   `C#`

Comment: Sorry, the language is Java.

Comment: It looks like you've tried exactly nothing before posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the mod operator(%)
    loop
        i += 1
        if i%5==0
           newline
    end

Comment: I think using the module operator is a good idea but can you put this in a small line of code?